# How add Auto serial Number by javascript after every click

Tags: javascript, ajax

[same serial number every row problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LsZ6y.png) Same serial after every click

```html
$(document).on('click', '.menu-item', function() {
    var menu_id = $(this).attr('id');
    var _token = $('input[name="_token"]').val();
    console.log(menu_id);
    var i = 1;
    $.ajax({
        url: '{{ url("waiter/menu/find") }}',
        method: 'POST',
        data: {menu_id:menu_id, _token:_token},
        dataType:"json",
        success: function(data) {
            $('#selectedMenu').append('<tr><td>' + i++  +'</td><td>' + data.name  + '</td><td><input type="number" name="quantity[]"></td><td>' + data.price + '</td><td><span class="btn btn-xs btn-danger"><i class="cancel fa fa-times"></i></span></td></tr>');
        }
    });
});
```

[How work i++ after every click for table serial no]

Comment: you are re initializing the i in the click each time. var i = 1; you may need to increase the scope of the variable to global.

Answer (score 1):

Everytime you click the `var i` get initialized to 1, so do that outside the `click` method.

Btw, this is not the correct method of doing it. First

1. Send the data to the server
2. Insert the row
3. Count the number of rows
4. Send the number back to the client
5. Display that as the Serial Number.